# AppInsights Query Specific time range EST

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I want to query appinsights logs for the query below between 7 am and 10 pm every day EST time. Any assistance around this is appreciated

```
dependencies
|where success == "False"
|where type == "Azure queue"
|where operation_Name == "XXXXTrigger"
```

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to query. You can change TimeZone like below two pic. Or you can use `new()-5h` to convert `EST` time.

## Method 1： change TimeZone

```
dependencies
|where success == "False"
|where type == "Azure queue"
|where operation_Name == "XXXXTrigger"
|where timestamp between(todatetime(strcat(format_datetime(now(),'yyyy-MM-dd')," ",'07:00:00')) .. todatetime(strcat(format_datetime(now(),'yyyy-MM-dd')," ",'22:00:00')))
```

[image]

[image]

## Method 2： `new()-5h`

```
dependencies
|where success == "False"
|where type == "Azure queue"
|where operation_Name == "XXXXTrigger"
|where timestamp between(todatetime(strcat(format_datetime(now()-5h,'yyyy-MM-dd')," ",'07:00:00')) .. todatetime(strcat(format_datetime(now()-5h,'yyyy-MM-dd')," ",'22:00:00')))
```